# Using grep (or similar) to get string AFTER first match

Tags: regex, linux, string, grep

Let's say I have some text in JSON:

```
{
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2": "value2"
    "key3": "value3"
    "key4": "value4"
    "key5": "value5"
}
{
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2": "value2"
    "key3": "value3"
    "key4": "value4"
    "key5": "value5"
}
```

What I want to do is find "value1", but only print "value5". There will be many "value5"(s), but I only want to print it if it is preceded by "value1" (which will be a unique string). I can't use `grep -Ax & -Bx`

As I don't want to match the line after, instead I want to print the string.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example file:

```
cat t
{
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2": "value2"
    "key3": "value3"
    "key4": "value4"
    "key5": "value5"
}
{
    "key1": "value6"
    "key2": "value2"
    "key3": "value3"
    "key4": "value4"
    "key5": "value5"
}
```

Print data in `key5` if `key1=value6`

```
awk '/key1/ && /value6/ {f=1} f && /key5/ {print $NF;f=0}'
"value5"
```